# SP List - JSON to change font for column list entries

Tags: sharepoint-online, list, modern-experience, flow, json-formatting

I have a Power Automate flow set up to copy email to a SP list, the column is set to rtf so that the list just has the email body rather than all the (I'm guessing) HTML stuff plain text gives but I'd like to format the column so the contents have just one font and size.

I'm not at all familiar with JSON and tried a few things but can't seem to get the column to change font.

Is there a way of doing this and, if so, could I be given an example of the JSON to use?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately, it is not possible using SharePoint JSON formatting.

SharePoint JSON formatting does not support applying JSON to Multi-Line Text column with enhanced rich text.

[image]

**Microsoft official documentation**: [Use column formatting to customize SharePoint](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/declarative-customization/column-formatting#supported-column-types)

---

You can try adding CSS styling in Power automate flow itself before adding email body to SharePoint list column.

**Update from comments**:

Check **HTML to Text** action in Power automate for extracting text from HTML email body.

**Microsoft documentation**: [Html to text action in Power Automate](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/connectors/conversionservice/)

Comment: Thanks Ganesh that’s a great straight forward answer. How would I go about adding CSS styling? Or there a way of extracting just the text from an email body?

Comment: Check HTML to Text action in Power automate for extracting text from HTML body.

Answer (score 0):

You can use "Html to text" action to convert the body content of the email to text.
[image]

[image]